# How do I manipulate a .txt file so that i can only print certain lines

Tags: python

What I want to do is make it only print lines which have the 5th column of my .txt file  less them the 3rd column. I have tried several times however I am new to python therefore any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def Option_B():
    print ("Estimate_Number","Customer_ID","Final_Total","Amount_Paid","Amount_Outstanding")
    f = open("paintingJobs.txt", "r")
    searchlines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    for A, line in enumerate(searchlines):
        if "A" in line and line[5]<line[3]:
            print (line)
```

This is what my .txt file looks like:

```
E5341,21/09/2015,C102,440,E,0
E5342,21/09/2015,C103,290,A,290
E5343,21/09/2015,C104,730,N,0
E5344,22/09/2015,C105,180,A,180
E5345,22/09/2015,C106,815,A,400
E5346,23/09/2015,C107,970,N,0
E5347,23/09/2015,C108,1050,E,0
E5348,23/09/2015,C109,370,A,200
E5349,25/09/2015,C110,480,A,250
E5350,25/09/2015,C111,330,A,330
E5351,25/09/2015,C112,1750,E,0
E5352,28/09/2015,C113,1500,N,0
E5353,28/09/2015,C114,272,A,200
E5354,29/09/2015,C115,560,E,0
E5355,29/09/2015,C116,530,A,450
E5356,29/09/2015,C117,860,E,0
E5357,29/09/2015,C118,650,E,0
E5358,29/09/2015,C119,380,A,380
E5359,29/09/2015,C120,980,N,0
E5360,30/09/2015,C121,1375,E,0
E5361,01/10/2015,C122,374,A,374
E5362,01/10/2015,C123,867,E,0
E5363,01/10/2015,C124,930,A,500
E5364,02/10/2015,C125,915,A,800
E5365,02/10/2015,C126,1486,A,1486
E5366,03/10/2015,C127,576,E,0
E5367,03/10/2015,C128,427,A,350
E5368,05/10/2015,C129,1346,A,1346
E5369,07/10/2015,C130,1756,N,0
E5370,07/10/2015,C131,432,E,0
E5371,10/10/2015,C132,289,A,289
E5372,10/10/2015,C133,923,E,0
E5373,10/10/2015,C134,1023,A,550
E5374,10/10/2015,C135,2070,E,0
E5375,10/10/2015,C136,687,N,0
E5376,13/10/2015,C137,297,A,297
E5377,13/10/2015,C138,829,E,0
E5378,13/10/2015,C139,1503,E,0
E5379,14/10/2015,C140,850,E,0
E5380,15/10/2015,C141,425,A,425
```

Comment: you forgot to (or may not know that you should) put the `split(',')`

Comment: I do not know how to split and how will this help me?

Comment: Something like `line.split(',')[5]<line.split(',')[3]` (not 5 and 3 but more like 4 and 2 though)...

Comment: So do I make sure each is split then after that will  my code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you are comparing the 3rd and 5th *character* in the line, not the 3rd and 5th column. You have to split by the comma-delimiter, and you should also convert those columns to integer before comparing:

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        columns = line.split(',')
        if "A" in columns and int(columns[5]) < int(columns[3]):
            print(line)
```

Or using the `csv` module:

```
import csv
with open("data.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for columns in reader: 
        if "A" in columns and int(columns[5]) < int(columns[3]):
            print(columns)
```

Comment: Thanks for that I have been stuck with this for ages

Answer (score 0):

Not a Python solution, but you can use [`awk`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) (`$0` is the whole line, `$6` is the 6th colum numbered starting at 1):

```
$ gawk -F , '$6 < $4 {print $0}' < so.txt
```

Output:

```
E5341,21/09/2015,C102,440,E,0
E5343,21/09/2015,C104,730,N,0
E5345,22/09/2015,C106,815,A,400
E5346,23/09/2015,C107,970,N,0
E5347,23/09/2015,C108,1050,E,0
E5348,23/09/2015,C109,370,A,200
E5349,25/09/2015,C110,480,A,250
E5351,25/09/2015,C112,1750,E,0
E5352,28/09/2015,C113,1500,N,0
E5353,28/09/2015,C114,272,A,200
E5354,29/09/2015,C115,560,E,0
E5355,29/09/2015,C116,530,A,450
E5356,29/09/2015,C117,860,E,0
E5357,29/09/2015,C118,650,E,0
E5359,29/09/2015,C120,980,N,0
E5360,30/09/2015,C121,1375,E,0
E5362,01/10/2015,C123,867,E,0
E5363,01/10/2015,C124,930,A,500
E5364,02/10/2015,C125,915,A,800
E5366,03/10/2015,C127,576,E,0
E5367,03/10/2015,C128,427,A,350
E5369,07/10/2015,C130,1756,N,0
E5370,07/10/2015,C131,432,E,0
E5372,10/10/2015,C133,923,E,0
E5373,10/10/2015,C134,1023,A,550
E5374,10/10/2015,C135,2070,E,0
E5375,10/10/2015,C136,687,N,0
E5377,13/10/2015,C138,829,E,0
E5378,13/10/2015,C139,1503,E,0
E5379,14/10/2015,C140,850,E,0
```